# "En" vs "les" as C.O.D ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

If you were saying "I don't know if they have any of those," what is the difference between saying *...s'ils les ont* and *...s'ils en ont* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that jumps to my mind is that *s'ils les ont* is definite, so you are talking about something that we know about, and you are saying *if they have them*. The second expression, *s'ils en ont*, is indefinite, so it would refer to something in bulk, maybe *if they have some*.

For example, we would say:

> Je vais chercher **ces deux livres** à la bibliothèque, mais je ne sais pas s'ils **les ont**.

which is: *I'm going to look for these two books in the library, but I don't know if they **have them**.*

whereas:

> Je vais chercher **des carottes** au marché, mais je ne sais pas s'ils **en ont**.

is: *I'm going to buy carrots at the farmer's market, but I don't know if they **have any**.*

It looks like a similar distinction can readily be made in English.

Comment: Agreed with the semantics here — though unlike in English, where "them" could be used for either case (it could replace "any" in the second example in informal speech), *les* couldn't appear in the second French example. Another way of stating the rule of thumb besides definiteness might be: if the object being replaced starts with *de*, use *en*.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - good points!